# Bashのスクリプトでブラウザ通信のみにプロキシを指定する方法

Tags: bash, network, google-chrome

### 問題

Bashスクリプトを通して、chromeブラウザが通信する際のみ指定したプロキシを使用したいのですが、そのようなことは可能でしょうか？
ネットワークに関する知識が曖昧なのでどのような記事を参考にしたら良いか教えて頂けないでしょうか？

### やりたい事

ブラウザ通信のプロキシを通信するたびにコロコロ変えながら通信をしたいです。chromeでリクエストを投げたら、プロキシをBashスクリプトで変えて、またリクエストを投げて、プロキシを変えてという事がやりたいです。
パソコンの通信全てを指定したプロキシで行う事はしたくないのでブラウザ通信のみに絞って、通信したいです。

### 考えてる事

1. プロキシが代理サーバを通して（IPアドレスが変わる）インターネットに接続する事は知っています。イメージは
   自分のIPアドレス隠すために使用されるイメージです。本来の使用方法がそのためなのかは分からないですが、プロキシサーバを中継する
   ことで場合によってはセキュリティが向上するんのではないかと思います。
2. ターミナルでプロキシを設定すると全ての通信がそのプロキシを経由する事になる気がする。ブラウザ通信のみでプロキシを使用したい。

   [image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
3. Macのネットワーク設定見てたら構成するプロトコルという物が出てきてこれでHTTP, HTTPSだけチェック入れればブラウザ通信のみをプロキシ経由に出来るんじゃないかと思ってる。
   ただ大体のアプリってHTTP, HTTPS通信を使用している気もする。MacのアプリNotion, Spotify等もそれらのプロトコルで通信しているような気がする。それ以外のプロトコルが一体どんな所で使用されか分からない。
   FTPはサーバにデータをアップするのに以前使用した事がある。HTTP等との違いがよく分からない、どちらもサーバとやり取りをしてる。
   ただ言語間の違いみたいなものでしょうか？
   よくたとえにある。日本語話者と英語話者と会話が出来ないみたいな。

Comment: chromeはPCのプロキシ設定に影響されるようです。手元のWindowsですが、chromeのメニュー - 設定 - 詳細設定 - システム とたどると「パソコンのプロキシ設定を開く」とあり、これをクリックすると Windows のプロキシ設定画面が表示されました。chrome にだけ設定する場合はコマンドラインオプションで設定できるもようです(試してないです) https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/network-settings

Comment: ありがとうございます。chromeを起動した状態のまま設定を変更出来たり出来るのでしょか？起動オプションで指定してそのあとプロキシを変更する際にchromeを一度閉じてから再び起動する必要がありそうです。

Comment: `--proxy-bypass-list=(<trailing_domain>|<ip-address>)[:<port>][;...]`これ使ったら出来そうな気がします。違うみたいです。http://electron.ebookchain.org/jp/api/chrome-command-line-switches.html

Answer (score 0):

bashではありませんが、[プロキシ自動設定ファイル](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/HTTP/Proxy_servers_and_tunneling/Proxy_Auto-Configuration_(PAC)_file)、いわゆるproxy.pacを使用されてはどうでしょうか？ proxy.pacはJavaScriptコードであり、ブラウザーがリクエスト毎に評価しどのプロキシを使用するべきかの判断を行います。使用するプロキシをコロコロ変えればいいと思います。

なお、Google Chromeは起動オプション [`--proxy-pac-url`](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/#proxy-pac-url) で指定できるみたいです。